# How to set major and minor grid lines using Achartengine on Android?

Tags: android, achartengine

I want to build chart with major and minor grids as the picture below, yet I can’t find API to implement this, can anyone help with how I can achieve this using Achartengine on Android? 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, AChartEngine does not support Major and Minor gridlines. Only one set of gridlines can be enabled, though you may enable/disable x and y gridlines separately.

```
renderer.setShowGridX(true);
renderer.setShowGridY(false);
```

If you absolutely need major/minor gridlines, I suggest you try [Sfchart](https://help.syncfusion.com/android/sfchart/overview).  It does support [major and minor axis](https://help.syncfusion.com/android/sfchart/axis) :

```
chart.getSecondaryAxis().setShowMajorGridLines(true);
chart.getSecondaryAxis().setShowMinorGridLines(true);
```

However, please make sure to check their licensing terms before using.